# SVNLook - repository format - syntax is incorrect

Tags: svn

I'm trying to run svnlook as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704901/search-in-svn-repository-for-a-file-name).

> C:\Users\name>svnlook tree svn://svn.compname.com:4345/ | grep
>   Shared.Translation
>
> svnlook: E720123: Can't open file 'svn:\svn.compname.com:4345\format':
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I got the repository-name/URL above from the repo-browser in Tortoise SVN. 
I have TortoiseSVN installed, but assuming I have to use command line to search the entire repository.

We have a large code base. I don't want to download it all. I need to find a program, when I don't know what hierarchy it is hidden under. Is there no way to do this with a full download? Also is there a way to download without getting the branches and tags?

Comment: This will probably be a silly suggestion, but did you try adding quotes around the repository-path?

Comment: fyi: http://biztalk-training.com/ in your profile is broken.

Comment: @Stanilas - quotes didn't help - apparently this command runs on local, not server anyway.

Comment: @bahrep - thanks, those @#$! hackers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be what I was looking for:

For Windows without Grep command:

> svn list -R https://subversion-repo/subfolder | findstr filename

or if you have a "grep" command:

> svn list -R https://subversion-repo/subfolder | grep filename

To search just the "Trunk" if you have grep command:

> svn list -R https://subversion-repo/subfolder | grep Trunk.*filename

It can take several minutes to run.

Source: http://foldingair.blogspot.com/2013/12/search-whole-svn-repository-for-given.html

Comment: Is there a way to limit this to just Master?  Maybe I could just add Master to my grep command.

Answer (score 2):

`svnlook` is only meant to work directly on the server hosting the repository, by looking at the repository database (directory) itself and *not* through a Subversion server process (svnserve or Apache). It's an administrative tool that's normally used from hook scripts.

Passing a repostory URL will not work; you must pass a filesystem path instead and that also implies you have access to the repository database via the filesystem. See [the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnlook)

Comment: We have a large code base.   I don't want to download it all.  I need to find a program, when I don't know what hierarchy it is hidden under.  Is there no way to do this with a full download?  Also is there a way to download without getting the branches and tags?

Comment: @NealWalters you need to read the Subversion manual, especially the parts about `svn list` (and since you're using TortoiseSVN, the Repository Browser) and *sparse checkouts*. No one could have guessed how to help you from the way you wrote your original question. This comment should have been part of, if not all of, your original question.

Comment: Yes, I'm having problems with the vocabulary.  Since Tortoise SVN has a "repo-browser" that seems to browse the server, I thought the word "repository" refers to the server.  We are phasing out SVN for GIT, so have to learn both.

Comment: The repository *is* what's stored on the server. But accessing it via a client is different from the direct filesystem access that `svnlook` requires.